# Equivalent of FIRST in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

*Edit: Answer is to use MIN. it works on both strings & numbers. Credit to @cadet down below.*

Original question:

I've been reading through similar questions around this for the last half an hour and cannot understand the responses so let me try to get a simple easy to follow answer.

What is the PostgresSQL equivalent to this code which I would write if I were using SQL Server, to bring back the first value in field2 when aggregating:

```
Select field1, first(field2) from table group by field1?
```

I have read that DISTINCT ON is the right thing to use? In that case would it be:
`Select field1, DISTINCT ON(field2) from table group by field1`? because that gives me a syntax error

Edit:

Here is the error stating that the FIRST function does not exist in PostGresSQL:

```
ERROR:  function first(asset32type) does not exist
LINE 1: Select policy, first (name) from multi_asset group by policy...
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 16
```

And in case it isn't already clear when I say that in SQL Server the first() function brings back the first value in field2 when aggregating, I mean if you had data like this:

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | 32 |
| Tom | 53 |

Then `select field1, first(field2) group by field1` would give you back:
Tom, 32   - i.e. it picks the first value from field2

Comment: What does this `first()` do? Not all of us speak Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: You mean MIN() ? And without the syntax error message, nobody can help you with that one either.

Comment: `first_value()` maybe?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In SQL server first brings back the first value in field2 when aggregating. I mentioned that in the post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top first() function is from microsoft access?

Comment: @mark Yes. See if edit above helps clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If first is related with specific order

```sql
select distinct field1, 
 first_value(field2) 
 over (partition by field1 order by field2) from 
 
 (
   values (1,10),(1,11),(1,12),(2,23),(2,24)
 ) as a(field1,field2)
```

If first is just minimum or maximum

```sql
select field1, 
 min(field2)
 from 
  (
   values (1,10),(1,11),(1,12),(2,23),(2,24)
 ) as a(field1,field2)
 group by field1
```

Comment: Ah ok. MIN worked. Surprised no one had mentioned that in all the posts I saw where people were asking something similar!

Comment: Well, the first one is something different from the smallest one. See Frank's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one, using DISTINCT ON():

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (field1)
  field1
, field2
FROM table
ORDER BY
 field1
, field2;
```

But without any data or any example, it's just a wild guess.